# memory/class area & multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

1. Into which part of the memory are static variables and class names 
   stored? Is it in the class/method area or some other area?
2. Where and into which part of the memory are the instruction of different methods loaded?
3. Does every thread have its own stack area or do they have a separate stack and as well a separate class/method area?
4. What instructions does the "run method" of the class Thread actually have?

Code example:

```
class A {
    static int a=5;  //where is this static a stored to?

    public void a() {
        System.out.prinln("hello"); //where is this instruction loaded to?
    }

    public static void b() {
        System.out.prinln("hi"); //where is this instruction loaded to? 
    }
}
```

Is there a different memory area for static methods and non static methods?

Comment: It's a lot of questions in one. And most of them can be answered with a bit of googling (that will probably bring you back to SO)...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #3: Every thread has its own stack.

It's not possible to answer your other questions, because they all depend on the JVM / underlying platform.

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer perspective, all you need to know is that it works, and usually it works fine. From a JVM perspective it very much depends on the implementation, and can vary, depending on where your code runs. But in the end - as said - it doesn't matter, because the code will execute exactly in the same way, no matter where it is running.